# Inserting rows, merging specific cells and adding specific text in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a specific amount of rows after I search for a specific cell value and merge some of the columns of those inserted cells.
I also want to add specific values to another column in the inserted cell.

Before you comment that I shouldn't merge the cells, it's what my boss wants.

The process the of system (Inputboxes) would go as follows:

1. Which value are you looking for?
2. Select the range in where you want to look.
3. How many rows would you like to add?
4. Which value would you like to have in row [array#]?
5. Which columns would you like to merge with the inserted rows?

In Excel, the process will look like this before
[image]

and like this after
[image]

There are now 3 more rows inserted after "Car". The column "type", "Tag number" and "Cost" are now merged, while "tire number" has 3 new added values "1", "2" and "3".

I already wrote a bit of code, to insert a dynamic amount of rows after I tell Excel for which cell value it needs to look.
How can I set the range for the merge of the cells and how can I add specific values in specific cells for each row I add. Basically, I don't understand the "Range" function in Excel.

```vb
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    inputSearch = InputBox("After which value would you like to add a row?")
    inputAmountOfRows = InputBox("How many Rows would you like to add?")
    inputColumnRangeCopy1 = InputBox("From which column would you like to start copying?")
    inputColumnRangeCopy2 = InputBox("From which column would you like to end copying?")

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)

    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = inputSearch Then
            For i = inputAmountOfRows To 1 Step -1
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                With Range(????)
                    .Merge
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                End With
            Next i
        End If
    Next xRowIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `inputAmountOfRows` variable to define an end of range, for example: Range( `"A" & xRowIndex & ":A" & xRowIndex + inputAmountOfRows)`. Got it?

Comment: Instead of the for loop? That doesn't really solve my problem. It only gives an alternative on how to write the code, unless I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly ....

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim inputSearch As String: Dim inputAmountOfRows As Integer
Dim c As Range: Dim fa As String: Dim addr As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

inputSearch = InputBox("Which value would you like to add a row?")
inputAmountOfRows = InputBox("How many rows would you need for " & inputSearch & "?")

Set c = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Find(inputSearch, lookat:=xlWhole)
If c Is Nothing Or c.MergeCells Then Exit Sub
fa = c.Address

    Do
        addr = c.Offset(0, -1).Address
        
        With Range(addr)
            .Resize(1, 4).Copy
            .Resize(inputAmountOfRows - 1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End With

        With Range(addr).Offset(0, 3)
            .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(inputAmountOfRows, 1), Type:=xlFillSeries
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = 0 To 2
        With Range(addr).Offset(0, i).Resize(inputAmountOfRows, 1)
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        End With
        Next i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set c = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).FindNext(c)
    
    Loop Until c.Address = fa

End Sub
```

inputSearch is where the user type such as Car, Bike, Plane, etc.
inputAmountOfRows is where the user type the number for **how many rows needed**.

The code first check if the inputSearch typed by the user is found in column 2. If it's not found or if it's found but the found cell is already merge then it exit the sub.

Then it loop to search if there is a next same value.

Within the loop :
it copy as many as the inputAmountOfRows.
if fill series column 3
it merge column A, B and C

To be honest, I don't understand this:
`inputColumnRangeCopy1 = InputBox("From which column would you like to start copying?")`
`inputColumnRangeCopy2 = InputBox("From which column would you like to end copying?")`
That's why I don't use it in the code above.

Please note, the code assume that each row in column D (Tire Number) value is 1 in the beginning condition.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough!